# Add elements to associative array inside a loop

Tags: php

I have String which look like this,

```
1|2|3|4
```

and I'm creating a array from that string by,

```
$arr = explode("|", $data['my_list']);
```

and then from each element of the array i need to pair with another value by creating associative array. After create, it should look like this,

```
1=>1
1=>2
1=>3
1=>4
```

so inside a loop I need to create this associative array. Can anybody please explain how to do this

Comment: Have you tried any solutions yet?

Comment: You can't have an array with duplicate keys.

Comment: `$arr` is already a array like `0->1,1->2,2->3,3->4`. Do you want dup keys ?

Comment: yes.is there possible way to do that

Comment: @Dushan no, but you could do a 2D array, like `$newArray[1] = $arr;`

Comment: if you tell us why you want same array keys (which is absolutly impossible) we might come up with an alternative solution to your problem.

Comment: solved the problem using array(array(1=>1),array(1=>2),array(1=>3))

Answer (score 0):

```
$tempArr = array();

$arr = explode("|", $data['my_list']);

foreach($arr as $item) {
    $tempArray['associative_with_key_' . $item] = 5; // where 5 is a new value
}
```